# Strict Standards: Declaration of RPA::PreLoadField() should be compatible with that of Foundation::PreLoadField()

Tags: php

When I run index.php and loads the page, it comes up with below error:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of RPA::PreLoadField() should be compatible with that of Foundation::PreLoadField() in C:\xampps\htdocs\Res\RPA.php on line 39

I've had a look at line 39 of RPA.php and this is class called:

```
class RPA extends Foundation
```

any ideas on this error?

This function is from foundations class:

```
public function PreLoadField($table, $column, $rowid, $coldata, &$value, $disabled=false)
        {
        $retval = false;

        if ($table === 'photos')
            {
            if ($column === 'blogentry')
                {
            $value = LookUpBlogEntries ($column, $coldata[$column]);
                $retval = true;     
                }
            }

        return $retval;
        }
```

This function is from RPA class:

```
public function PreLoadField($table, $column, $rowid, $coldata, &$value)
        {
        $retval = parent::PreLoadField($table, $column, $rowid, $coldata, &$value);

        return $retval;
        }
```

RPA extends Foundation..

Comment: Foundations::PreLoadField has 1 parameter more than RPA::PreLoadFields ($disabled).  You need to add $disabled = false to your RPA method.

Comment: This has been added but still not working!

Comment: Different message now?  Or not doing anything?  What do you mean by not working?

Comment: It looks like your comment was cut off?

Answer (score 2):

My guess (since you didn't post enough code to tell) is that you're over riding a method in a parent class with a different signature.  Like:

```
class A
{
    public function blah($a, $b) { }
}

class B extends class A
{
    public function blah($a) { }
}
```

PHP will complain about that (as it should).  Does calling code need to provide 1 argument or two?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar warnings when I turned E_STRICT on in a joomla installation. In every single case I checked both functions and found that the problem was the number of parameters passed in one function was different than the other. As a general rule I was able to fix all errors by adding the missing parameter (something like $param = null).

I suggest you do a search on your entire code to see how both functions are being called. This will probably give you a clue about how to fix the problem.

Good luck!

PS: by the way, in my experience you don't necessarily have to fix those warnings. In my case joomla was working fine before I fixed the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file you need to change your error_reporting setting to exclude **E_STRICT**. 
For instance:
error_reporting(**E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE**);

Please note that **E_ALL** also causes the issue because it includes **E_STRICT** since PHP#5.0.0.